Merge same column name data and make it as single for a single dataframe
I have the below columns in my dataframe ABC.

userLabel
userLabel

Both are same name
For example
data = {'userLabel': ['a', '', 3, '', 'b'],
        'name':['abc', 'def', 'ghi', '', 'ijk'],
        'userLabel1': ['', '2', '', '4', '']}


ABC = pd.DataFrame(data).rename(columns={'userLabel1':'userLabel'})
print (ABC)
  userLabel name userLabel
0         a  abc          
1            def         2
2         3  ghi          
3                        4
4         b  ijk          

I need to club both and make it as a single column userLabel.
I need like below
ABC = {'userLabel': ['a', '2', 3, '4', 'b'],
       'name':['abc', 'def', 'ghi', '', 'ijk']}

I tried the below code but didn't work
ABC['userLabel'] = ABC['userLabel'].fillna(ABC['userLabel'])


Do you have other columns? Can you provide a [mre] as DataFrame constructor for clarity?

Thanks for clarifying, I updated accordingly ;)

You could select the column(s), replace the empty strings, bfill and slice:
target = 'userLabel'
out = (ABC.drop(columns=target)
          .assign(**{target: ABC[[target]].replace('', None)
                                          .bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]})
       )

Or as suggested by @ouroboros1, combined with pop:
ABC['userLabel'] = ABC.pop('userLabel').replace('', None).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]

Output:
  name userLabel
0  abc         a
1  def         2
2  ghi         3
3              4
4  ijk         b

Or, a variant with groupby.first, which would handle other duplicated columns:
out = ABC.replace('', None).groupby(axis=1, level=0, sort=False).first()

Which, in new pandas versions should be performed as a transpose:
out = ABC.T.replace('', None).groupby(level=0, sort=False).first().T

Output:
  userLabel  name
0         a   abc
1         2   def
2         3   ghi
3         4  None
4         b   ijk


With pop you can assign it right back, no? df['userLabel'] = df.pop('userLabel').replace('', None).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, :1].

You can replace spaces to missing values first, forward filling missing values and select last column, last remove duplicated userLabel column(s):
ABC['userLabel'] = ABC['userLabel'].replace('', np.nan).ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]

ABC = ABC.loc[:, ~ABC.columns.duplicated() | (ABC.columns != 'userLabel')]

print (ABC)
  userLabel name
0         a  abc
1         2  def
2         3  ghi
3         4     
4         b  ijk

Thank you @ouroboros1 fr suggestion using DataFrame.pop, for original ordering add DataFrame.reindex:
data = {'userLabel': ['a', '', 3, '', 'b'],
        'name':['abc', 'def', 'ghi', '', 'ijk'],
        'userLabel1': ['', '2', '', '4', ''],
        'col':7}


ABC = pd.DataFrame(data).rename(columns={'userLabel1':'userLabel'})

cols = ABC.columns
ABC = (ABC.assign(userLabel = ABC.pop('userLabel')
                                 .replace('',  np.nan)
                                 .ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1])
          .reindex(cols[~cols.duplicated()], axis=1))
print (ABC)
  userLabel name  col
0         a  abc    7
1         2  def    7
2         3  ghi    7
3         4         7
4         b  ijk    7


Same here, you can use pop and assign: df['userLabel'] = df.pop('userLabel').replace('', np.nan).ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1].
